# Is there any way to perform ant all from hac in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to do frequently code changes in Hybris and test it on the server on my local setup. so every time I need  stop the server and perform ant all then again start the server. this process takes at least of 15 minutes.

ant update updates the whole system where i just need to rebuild my java classes. so is there any way I can perform **ant all** or build java files again while server is running.

Comment: Hi @Kunal 
you can use ant build and it will generate new pojo class or any attribute you added and you can utilize in code but it will not get swapped,you need to restart to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JRebel for dynamic class replacement in runtime. JRebel tracking updated class and spring config files and replace them in runtime. Also you can try to use HotSwapAgent for free but JRebel is best option.